# Change color of multiple elements using a color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how I can change the color of all elements with the class of "change" using the [Really Simple Bootstrap Color Picker](http://b3nj4m.github.io/really-simple-bootstrap-color-picker/). Here is the JS code.

```
$(function() {
  var $inputs = $('input.color');
  $inputs.colorPicker({pickerDefault: '#99CCFF'});

  $inputs.each(function(idx, item) {
    var $input = $(item);
    var $target = $input.parents('.control-group:first').find('label:first');
    $target.css('color', $input.val());

    $input.on('colorPicker:preview colorPicker:change', function(e, value) {
      $target.css('color', value);
    });

    $input.on('colorPicker:addSwatch', function(e, value) {
      //do something with custom color (e.g. persist on the server-side)
    });
  });
});
```

HTML (I dont plan on using a form for all my elements. None of the elements below have a class of "change". I just included the code I had originally.)

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Pick a Color</label>
    <div class="controls input-prepend">
      <input type="text" name="color" class="color addSwatch" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Pick a Color</label>
    <div class="controls input-prepend">
      <input type="text" name="color" class="color input-small" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Might help if you mentioned which color picker plugin you're using. There's a bunch of them out there.

Comment: Its called Really Simple Bootstrap Color Picker.
http://b3nj4m.github.io/really-simple-bootstrap-color-picker/

Comment: Are you getting the correct value during the `colorPicker:preview colorPicker:change` event? What is stopping you from doing `$('.change').css('color', value)`?

Comment: Yes. I can make one work. How do I make two or more work, using the html and javascript above. Thanks.

Comment: I literally handed you the code for it if you want to change all elements with a class of `change`. Modify that to suit your needs.